# Quickest way to create and populate a table in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have an text file with a couple hundred records in it. I want to be able to join this information with another table. Currently, the only way I can think of is to create a table with CREATE and then use hundreds of INSERT INTO's (since INSERT INTO in Teradata doesn't support multiple insert values)

Is there a more efifcient way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "Teradata doesn't support multiple input values"?  If you had the data in a table, you should be able to do an insert as select into the next table.

Comment: MLoad? FastLoad?  If you're using SQL assistant, you can build all your inserts (use excel or whatever), paste them into SQL Assistant, select all the inserts, and hit f9.  That will execute the inserts as a multi-statement request (I think that's what it's called), as opposed to hundreds of individual insert statements.  It's significantly faster.

Comment: If those records are in a readable delimited format you can batch load them using Studio or SQL Assistant without submitting lots of inserts

Answer (score 0):

Link the table in MS$Access, and paste the content of the text file directly into the Teradata table records. A rather fast method for small files, if you do it non-automated.